# Why is Postgres service failing?

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm setting up a ManageIQ appliance for development.  When I updated the 'v2_key' encryption key to be same as production, my db connection croaked.  Initially I got these errors:

```
Aug 31 13:26:59 miq-dev.chq.ei sh[3642]: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"

Aug 31 13:26:59 miq-dev.chq.ei sh[3642]: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "root", database "vmdb_production", SSL off
```

I updated my pg_hba.conf to:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER  ADDRESS METHOD
local   all     all             trust
local   all         all           peer map=usermap
local   replication all           peer map=usermap
hostssl all         all   all     md5
host    replication all   all     md5
::1     vmdb_production root            trust        # <--- added last line
```

Now I get a new set of errors:

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-08-31 18:39:44 EDT; 49s ago
  Process: 3648 ExecStart=/usr/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3645 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postgresql-check-db-dir %N (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3648 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 31 18:39:44 miq-dev.chq.ei postmaster[3648]: 2020-08-31 18:39:44 EDT::5f4d7c30.e40:@:[3648]:LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
Aug 31 18:39:44 miq-dev.chq.ei postmaster[3648]: 2020-08-31 18:39:44 EDT::5f4d7c30.e40:@:[3648]:LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
Aug 31 18:39:44 miq-dev.chq.ei postmaster[3648]: 2020-08-31 18:39:44 EDT::5f4d7c30.e40:@:[3648]:LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresq...QL.5432"
Aug 31 18:39:44 miq-dev.chq.ei postmaster[3648]: 2020-08-31 18:39:44 EDT::5f4d7c30.e40:@:[3648]:LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
Aug 31 18:39:44 miq-dev.chq.ei postmaster[3648]: 2020-08-31 18:39:44 EDT::5f4d7c30.e40:@:[3648]:LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
Aug 31 18:39:44 miq-dev.chq.ei postmaster[3648]: 2020-08-31 18:39:44 EDT::5f4d7c30.e40:@:[3648]:HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
Aug 31 18:39:44 miq-dev.chq.ei systemd[1]: postgresql.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 31 18:39:44 miq-dev.chq.ei systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
Aug 31 18:39:44 miq-dev.chq.ei systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
Aug 31 18:39:44 miq-dev.chq.ei systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

which tells me postgresql service is not running.

I tried the suggestion from this SO post: [Postgresql12.3 wont start on boot, systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206481/postgresql12-3-wont-start-on-boot-systemd) by adding a few lines to my postgresql.service file, but I still get the same ol errors.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you

Comment: How did you come up w/ `::1     vmdb_production root            trust`?  That needs to be `host vmdb_production root     ::1/128 trust` to make sense syntactically; that said, using `root` and `trust` is probably not the smartest idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) the first "column" of the `pg_hba.conf` must be one of `local`, `host`, `hostssl`, `hostnossl`, `hostgssenc` or `hostnogssenc`. You can't put an IP address into the first column, it goes into the 4th column (if the first is not `local`).

The database needs to be put into the third column, then the username, **then** the IP address.

So this line:

```
::1     vmdb_production root            trust
```

should be:

```
host   vmdb_production   root  ::1  trust
```

This assumes you do have a **Postgres** user `root` which would be highly unusual. It might even indicate that you are trying to run that software under `root` which is a really, really bad idea (*espcially* in combination with `trust`)

But the root cause, why Postgres isn't starting, is the invalid entry in `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. That totally makes sense now. PG now says it will accept connections. The software is set to use root OOTB. It won't authenticate my root user, tho. When I decrypt the pw saved in the database.yml file it decrypts properly.